# ios UIActivityViewController excludedActivityTypes is disabling Facebook and Twitter

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to disable sharing using texting/messages with following line:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypeMessage];
```

But it is disabling Facebook and Twitter and Weibo.

Any of you know why this is happening?

Comment: Have you set up your Facebook/Twitter accounts in settings?

Comment: If you haven't set up the accounts, they won't show up as activity options in the share menu.